# Can I Display Path Information for Ant Buildfiles in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, ant

In Eclipse 4.2, is there a way to  display path or project name information for an Ant build file that is included in the Ant View?

In my workspace, I currently have two versions of my project checked out, one from our myproject/trunk, and another from myproject/branches/feature

From each branch, I've dragged the appropriate build.xml from the project into the Ant View.  However, since both the trunk and the feature branch have the same Project Name and same targets, its impossible  to tell the difference between the two in the Ant View.  Is there a way to either a) Show the associated project name/path for the build.xml or b) rename the display without editing the build.xml directly?

I know that I could manually update the Project Name for every branch/tag in my repository to use a custom name, but this seems like a hack more than a solution.  Is there a better way?

Below is a mockup of what I'd like to do.

[image: Mockup of what I'd like to see]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like this is currently possible.  I filed a bug report with the Eclipse project, so more information may be available at a future date.  The link to the bug report is below

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=403514

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin => [r2tech-eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/r2tech-eclipse/)
The [screenshot](http://r2tech-eclipse.sourceforge.net/antview-2.2.jpg) shows AntView that lists buildfiles with path.

**EDIT** : doesn't work with Eclipse 3.7.x (Indigo), the latest release is from 2002.
Sources are available for download, so you may use it to patch the ant view eclipse ships with.
The eclipse builtin ant view should provide the same features.
Another option is to [fill a bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) with a feature request for the ant view.

For accessing the buildfilelocation from inside the build script make the projectpath
available as property for ant like that :

```
Window > Preferences > Ant > Runtime > Properties
```

and create a property named projectpath with value :

```
${project_loc}
```

then in your buildscript use something like :

```
<echo>$${projectpath} => ${projectpath}</echo>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update.  We're currently using Eclipe 4.2, I edited the question to include that detail.   Including it in the buildfile doesn't really help, since I'd like to know *before* I run the buildfile.